# Implementing Algorithms in RenderScript

Tags: android, c, gpu, renderscript, jts

I am currently doing a project on benchmarking GPU performance vs CPU performance in mobile devices (Android) through a variety of algorithms. (Mainly computational geometric ones)

The problem I am currently facing, is how to implement these algorithms efficiently using RenderScript. For example, given a Topology Library which contains several algorithms such as Point in Polygon Algorithm, do I have to manually rewrite these algorithms in C for use with RenderScript, or is there some magical way to utilize them in RenderScript without having to rewrite the algo?

For example, I am using the JTS Topology Suite (for Java) and am trying to implement the Point in Polygon Analysis. Do I have to rewrite the entire algorithm in C, or find an external C library and import it into renderscript, or some magical way to utilize them in RS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code can probably be reused, but you will have to make modifications in any case. If you are really unfamiliar with C, this might be a good way to get better at C and RenderScript.

Comment: Can I actually import an external C library into renderscript? I tried doing so but renderscript cropped up a lot of errors.

Comment: No. Many C library headers are going to need small modifications to be able to work with RS. Our use of "static" vs. "extern" to indicate whether or not the variable is visible to Java is one such difference that usually requires a developer to inspect the headers/sources when porting.